# Regex to split string and Date

Tags: c#, regex, split

I'm trying to split a pattern such as `John Doe 12/01/1950`, `John * Doe 12/01/1950`, `John 12/01/1950`, `12/01/1950 John` and `12/01/1950 John * Doe` using C#. The expected Result is the date in one string and the rest in another...

Comment: Did you try _anything_ to solve your problem?

Comment: @SonerGönül He posted it on stack overflow :)

Comment: to be completally honest, not yet... this fell out of the sky for me now and its 6 days overdue... and i dont know how to construct regex... i'm starting to look around though...

Comment: If you are allowed to use multiple regexes, I would: use string.split(',') and then do two separate regexes and use the one that gets a match.  Otherwise, the case where the date is first, vs. last will be quite complicated.

Comment: The lazy way would be to split on space then check each with date.tryparse.  If it is a date then store that in one var and the rest of the items append to second var.

Comment: @Derek good-enough idea! how come i didnt think of it before...

Answer (score 2):

Match a date with

```
(\d+/){2}\d+
```

That is, one or more digits, followed by a slash, repeat twice, followed by one or more digits.  If you want to be specific about how many digits they put, you can use

```
\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d
```

We can match the name by searching for word characters (\w)

```
(\w+ +\* +\w+)|(\w+ +\w+)|(\w+)
```

which means "word spaces star spaces word" or "word spaces word" or "word" respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
string[] lines = new[] {
    "John Doe 12/01/1950",
    "John * Doe 12/01/1950",
    "John 12/01/1950",
    "12/01/1950 John",
    "12/01/1950 John * Doe" };
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    Match m = Regex.Match(line, @"(?<name1>.*?)\s?(?<date>\d\d/\d\d/\d{4})\s?(?<name2>.*)");
    string date = m.Groups["date"].Value;
    string name = m.Groups["name1"].Value + m.Groups["name2"].Value;
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", date, name);
}
```